# php variable in jquery appended form

Tags: php, jquery

i am having trouble geting a php variable that is available on the page inside a form that i am appending through a bookmarklet

bookmarklet code:

```
<a class="bookmarklet" href="javascript:(function(){var%20script=document.createElement('script');script.src='http://webcreationcentre.com.au/manage/manage.js';document.body.appendChild(script);})()">title checker</a>
```

manage.js code:

```
(function(){

// the minimum version of jQuery we want
var v = "1.3.2";

// check prior inclusion and version
if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery < v) {
    var done = false;
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/" + v + "/jquery.min.js";
    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete")) {
            done = true;
            initMyBookmarklet();
        }
    };
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
} else {
    initMyBookmarklet();
}

function initMyBookmarklet() {
    (window.myBookmarklet = function() {

    var title = '<?php echo $data->title; ?>';
    alert(title);

    $('body').append($('<div></div>').css('width','100%')
        .append($('<form></form>')
        .append($('<label for="title">Title</label>'))
        .append($('<input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $data->title; ?>">'))));
        // your JavaScript code goes here!
    })();
}

})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your JS is just in a static file called `manage.js` then PHP will never be processing it, so simply adding `<?php ... ?>` into it won't do anything useful.

If it *was* being procesed by PHP (e.g. it was actually `manage-js.php`), it still wouldn't be part of the *same* PHP page as the one which you happen to be running your bookmarklet on (you could run your bookmarklet on StackOverflow, for all the PHP cared) so `$data->title` would have to be defined further up in the PHP file that was generating the JS, and would know nothing about where you ran the bookmarklet.

Comment: Thanks that make more sense is there a way i can get php vars from current page? (ajax or something)

Comment: @MitchellBray No. The only thing you can get from the *current* page is its output, i.e. the HTML it generated. Any AJAX call would be, again, a new PHP page. The life cycle of a PHP page begins with what the browser asks for, and ends with what is sent back to the browser; after that, it no longer exists anywhere.

Comment: To put it more positively: only if you output that variable somewhere in the page's HTML (e.g. in a hidden div with a particular id; or using an HMTL5 data-* attribute like `<body data-title="...">`, which jQuery can read as `$('body').data('title')`)